# why has my javascript canvas drawing function gone haywire?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Canvas iterator supposed to randomize a 20px^2 square between yellow and green across the canvas but for some unknown reason, the pixels are wider than squares until about halfway through the canvas, where the pixels fragment into very tall columns.

The expected result is to have a canvas filling the screen made up of 20x20pixel squares of random yellow or green color, which the canvas automatically scales to change the size and aspect ratio to accommodate window resizing.

The actual result is the canvas seems to produce a third of the screen as very short and wide pixels with the expected color pattern followed below by very tall columns, followed by the page behind all of this.

I've asked around elsewhere to no avail, and I'm looking for any solution that meets the desired goal, so I'm open to anything.

[Source](https://canvas-testing.grify.repl.co) [replit](https://repl.it/@Grify/canvas-testing)
snippet:

```js
var has = false
var hasLoaded = false
 
console.log(window.innerHeight)
console.log(window.innerWidth)
console.log(window.innerWidth*1.5)



var has = false
function toggle() {
 console.log("" + has.toString())
 if(has){
  has = false
  document.getElementById('cx').classList.remove('filtered')
 }else{
  has = true
  document.getElementById('cx').classList.add('filtered')
 }
}

function resize() {
 //window resize event to find canvas size
 var h = window.innerHeight
 var w = window.innerWidth
 var p = 20
 var ph = Math.floor(h/p)
 var pw = Math.floor(w/p)
 let refcx = document.getElementById('cx')
 refcx.width = pw
 console.log("resized")
 dynDraw(w, h, pw, ph, p);
}


function dynDraw(w, h, pw, ph, p) {
 //wha
 //for drawing after resize event

 console.log(w + "w, "+h+"h, "+pw+"pw, "+ph+"ph")
 var c = document.getElementById("cx");
 var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 
 ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false
 //ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000"
 //ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
 ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00"

 for(let row = 0; row <= ph; row++)
 { //each row accross width lines, ph stacks
  for(let i = 0; i <= pw; i++)
  { //each pixel across height lines, pw stacks
   Math.random() >= 0.5 ? ctx.fillStyle = "#fff000" : ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00"
   ctx.fillRect(i, row, pw, pw)
   console.log(i + "," + row + "," + pw + "," + ph)
  }
 }
 console.log("done")
}
```

```css
#cx {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;

    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;

 z-index: -5;
}
.filtered {
 image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
 image-rendering: -webkit-crisp-edges;
 image-rendering: pixelated;
 image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width">
        <title>Canvas Testing</title>
        <link href = "style.css" rel = "stylesheet"></link>
    
        <script src = "script.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body onload="resize();" >
  <button id="buttonToDoStuff" onclick="toggle();">toggle filter</button>
        <canvas id="cx" width="100" height="100">
            
            Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
            
        </canvas>

    </body>

</html>
```

[image: the canvas]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
ctx.fillRect(i, row, pw, pw)
```

should probably be

```
ctx.fillRect(i, row, 1, 1)
```

instead.

You also need to set both `width` and `height` in the `resize` handler. You only set `width`.

The issue is because you've sized the canvas draw area (the context) such that each square you want is 1x1 relative to the context dimensions. The `<canvas>`'s `width` and `height` attributes control the canvas element and the canvas drawing context dimensions. The CSS `width` and `height` override the element dimensions but do not effect the drawing context dimensions, the drawing context is instead stretched to fit the element.

```js
var has = false
var hasLoaded = false
 
console.log(window.innerHeight)
console.log(window.innerWidth)
console.log(window.innerWidth*1.5)



var has = false
function toggle() {
 console.log("" + has.toString())
 if(has){
  has = false
  document.getElementById('cx').classList.remove('filtered')
 }else{
  has = true
  document.getElementById('cx').classList.add('filtered')
 }
}

function resize() {
 //window resize event to find canvas size
 var h = window.innerHeight
 var w = window.innerWidth
 var p = 20
 var ph = Math.floor(h/p)
 var pw = Math.floor(w/p)
 let refcx = document.getElementById('cx')
 refcx.width = pw
  refcx.height = ph
 console.log("resized")
 dynDraw(w, h, pw, ph, p);
}


function dynDraw(w, h, pw, ph, p) {
 //wha
 //for drawing after resize event

 console.log(w + "w, "+h+"h, "+pw+"pw, "+ph+"ph")
 var c = document.getElementById("cx");
 var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false
 //ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000"
 //ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
 ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00"

 for(let row = 0; row <= ph; row++)
 { //each row accross width lines, ph stacks
  for(let i = 0; i <= pw; i++)
  { //each pixel across height lines, pw stacks
   Math.random() >= 0.5 ? ctx.fillStyle = "#fff000" : ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00"
   ctx.fillRect(i, row, 1, 1)
   console.log(i + "," + row + "," + pw + "," + ph)
  }
 }
 console.log("done")
}
```

```css
#cx {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;

    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;

 z-index: -5;
}
.filtered {
 image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
 image-rendering: -webkit-crisp-edges;
 image-rendering: pixelated;
 image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width">
        <title>Canvas Testing</title>
        <link href = "style.css" rel = "stylesheet"></link>
    
        <script src = "script.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body onload="resize();" >
  <button id="buttonToDoStuff" onclick="toggle();">toggle filter</button>
        <canvas id="cx">
            
            Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
            
        </canvas>

    </body>

</html>
```